# Oculus Integration on Unity 5.1.2 not showing Oculus Lenses (like two black boxes) when debugging/editor

Tags: unity, oculus

I added Oculus Utilities for Unity 5.1.2, created a simple scene, added OVRCharacterController prefab, it works fine like normal fps controller but as far as I know, it should show something like 2 separate display screen on monitor with that black distortion outline frame. I have no hmd. The runtime is running, and OVR service is also running. It is set to extended mode. One thing to note here is that there is no Oculus setting option in player settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this is the way it work in Unity5 and above so there was nothing to worry about.